# Nexmo API: Is there any method or API to cancel ongoing outbound or inbound call in Nexmo?

Tags: vonage

I want to disconnect an ongoing call from my server based on some circumstances. Is there any Nexmo API through which I can do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Got answer to my query. Bit of more searching and study found my answer.

I can modify in-progress call by making a PUT call to below URL.

https://api.nexmo.com/v1/calls/:uuid

where UUID is uuid of call.
have to give action = 'hangup'